# create object for class inheriting QLayout

Tags: qt, inheritance, abstract-class, qlayout

I have a screen class as

```
   class Screen : public QLayout 
   {
   public:
       Screen();
       ~Screen();
       void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e);
   };
```

When I am creating the object I got an error that can not create an object for pure abstract class. Since QLayoput is pure abstract , How can I create an object for a class which is inherits the QLayout ?

definitions:

```
Screen::Screen( )
{

}

Screen::~Screen()
{
    delete this ;
    //Screen(new QSize (100,100));
}


void Screen::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e)
{


}
```

Comment: I have not added any code in screen instance, I wanted to make a copy of QLayout to use in my widget class, I wanted QLayout properties only,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QLayout is pure abstract, meaning it has virtual members without a definition. To subclass it, you need to provide definitions for all such methods in your class. Specifically, Qt Docs state that

> To make your own layout manager, implement the functions `addItem()`,
>   `sizeHint()`, `setGeometry()`, `itemAt()` and `takeAt()`.

For more, see there (there are additional optional advices for further functions which should be implemented): http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlayout.html